# SQL to LINQ, group by and sum

Tags: sql, linq, group-by

Trying write a simple SQL query as LINQ.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT p.id, p.customer, SUM(pd.total_price)
FROM purchases p JOIN purchases_details pd ON p.id = pd.purchase_id
GROUP BY pd.purchase_id
```

My best LINQ so far:

```
var purchases_with_details = from p in db.Purchases
                             join pd in db.Purchases_details on p.Id equals pd.purchase_id
                             group pd by pd.purchase_id into pdg
                             select new { ??? };
```

Problem is that I can only write `pdg.*` in the `select new { }`.

I would like to write something like `{ p.id, p.customer, pdg.Sum(o => o.total_price) }`

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Is that sum expression not working for you?

Comment: The sum expression is working, but I cannot write the p.* parts (i.e. p.id and p.customer)

Comment: try pdg.id, pdg.customer

Comment: Still get "The name 'p' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: That SQL isn't even valid. `p.customer` is invalid since you haven't included it in the group by clause... are you grouping by that column as well?

Comment: Don't use the (LINQ) `join` statement just because SQL does. Create and use navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold any links or example of how to use navigation properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
     var purchases_with_details = from pd in db.Purchases_details
                                         group pd by pd.purchase_id into pdg
                                         //join *after* group
                                         join p in db.Purchases on pdg.Key equals p.Id
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             Id = p.Id,
                                             Cust =p.customer,
                                             TotalPrice = pdg.Sum(y => y.total_price)
                                         };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
var purchases_with_details = from p in db.Purchases
                             join pd in db.Purchases_details on p.Id equals pd.purchase_id
                             group pd by pd.purchase_id into pdg
                             select new { 
                                 PurchaseID=pdg.Key.purchase_id,
                                 TOTAL=pdg.Sum(x=>x.total_price)
                             };
```